# Hardcode datadir path upon installing executable

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, cabal-install

Problem: I've got a command-line tool written in Haskell that reads a data file. Upon installing the program, I'd like for the program to be able to read that data file regardless of the directory I find myself in. That is, upon installing, the path that the program knows should be aligned with the path that the installer chooses.

Initial attempt: I was directed to the section [7.6. Accessing data files from package code](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-package.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code) in Cabal (the library) and learned that I can import `getDataDir :: IO FilePath` from `Paths_myprog`, as long as I add `Paths_myprog` to `other-modules` (although [Hpack auto-includes this](https://github.com/sol/hpack#handling-of-paths_-modules) by default) and that after installing my program, I can run it with:

```
myprog_datadir=~/tmp ~/.local/bin/myprog
```

Then all I need to do is have the installer move the data file to this directory, since `myprog` dynamically accesses that path rather than some hardcoded value. But I don't want to have to specify `myprog_datadir=~/tmp` in my environment every time I run the program, I want it hardcoded into the binary! And it seems that setting `myprog_datadir=~/tmp` when building and installing doesn't set a compile-time default.

So: Is there a way I can hardcode this path upon installation?

(Preferrably, an answer that relates to Stack, but a cabal-install answer is also greatly appreciated.)

Comment: The file is listed as `data-files: relative/path/to/file.txt`, but as I install the executable and change directory, that relative path no longer exists. The default `datadir` is something like `/Users/simonshine/Projects/myprog/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/d6f6bad3f39945fab394a08b1bc4be948440a07b57dc3d9c354985b39ee09310/8.8.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.8.4/myprog-0.1.0`, but I'd like for that to be e.g. `/usr/local/share`.

Comment: Have you considered hardcoding _the data itself_ into the executable, rather than just a path to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files listed in `data-files` are already automatically installed in the right location so that `Paths_pkg` will find them. Here's a minimal example:

```
% cat Main.hs
import Paths_so_test
main :: IO ()
main = getDataDir >>= putStrLn
% cat so-test.cabal
cabal-version:       >=1.10
name:                so-test
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
data-files:          test

executable so-test
  main-is:             Main.hs
  other-modules:       Paths_so_test
  autogen-modules:     Paths_so_test
  build-depends:       base >=4.14 && <4.15
  default-language:    Haskell2010
% cat test
Hello, world!
% cabal install
Wrote tarball sdist to
/home/dmwit/projects/oneoff/tmp.dir/dist-newstyle/sdist/so-test-0.1.0.0.tar.gz
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
Symlinking 'so-test'
% cat `so-test`/test
Hello, world!
```

Comment: But how do I change that? If the installer were `configure`, I might write `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` and then `datarootdir` would be `${prefix}/share`. My scenario is that I imagine some packager (myself, really) would call `stack install` and specify paths that my packaging tool will then go to and bundle up whichever way it does (e.g. PPA, AUR).

Comment: I might like the equivalent of `--prefix=~/.local` so that not only the executable ends up in `~/.local/bin`, but also data files end up in `~/.local/share` with `myprog_datadir=~/.local/share` being the default instead of the really long name with a hash in it.

Comment: @SimonShine `~/.cabal/config` should have stanzas labeled `install-dirs user` and `install-dirs global`.